# Kotlin: Java can't resolve Kotlin Symbol?

Tags: java, kotlin, single-instance

I have a Kotlin Code just like the below, `SingleKotlin.instance` can be called by the other Kotlin files

```
class SingleKotlin private constructor(){
    companion object {
        val instance by lazy {
            SingleKotlin()
        }
    }

}
```

However, when I try to call `SingleKotlin.instance` from java, it shows can't resolve symbol 'instance'

I don't understand why, anybody can explian and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add @JvmStatic annotation above field (as said in this documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields)

So, your code should be like this:

```
class SingleKotlin private constructor(){
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val instance by lazy {
            SingleKotlin()
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can call it like

```
SingleKotlin.instance
```

Comment: Thanks for Yurii Kyrylchuk answer, after add @JvmField, in java code, I have to use "SingleKotlin.getInstance()"

Comment: `@JvmField` cannot be applied to a delegated property, however `@JvmStatic` can. It would make the getter of that property exposed in the static scope of the containing class, so you have to call that getter as `SingleKotlin.getInstance()`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, after added @JvmStatic, I use SingleKotlin.getInstance()"

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@YuriiKyrylchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793494/yurii-kyrylchuk)'s answer: another option (and the only option if you don't have control over the Kotlin code) is to refer to `MyClass.Companion` from Java. Example:

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        val x: Int = 0
    }
}
```

And in Java:

```
MyClass.Companion.getX();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `SingleKotlin` object has a single private constructor without parameters, you can use `object` instead:

```
object SingleKotlin {
    // some members of SingleKotlin
    val x = 42
}
```

Then in Java you reference it through the `INSTANCE` static field:

```
SingleKotlin single = SingleKotlin.INSTANCE;
// or
SingleKotlin.INSTANCE.getX();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method from Java like this:
`AppUIUtils.Companion.yourMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

In additional to Ilya answer you can use @JvmStatic annotation

```
object SingleKotlin {
    // some members of SingleKotlin

    @JvmStatic val x = 42
}
```

Then in Java

```
SingleKotlin.getX();
```